# How to add wrangler connection to cloud sql postgres in Cloud Data Fusion

Tags: cloud, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-data-fusion

I am not able to see the option to add connection to "Cloud Sql Postgres" under **wrangler -> databases**.
I can only see these options
[avaialable-connection-options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qra9Z.png)

If i select the postgressql and add the details i get the `Error: SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out`

My connection to this instance works from the studio using the source/sink **CloudSQL PostgreSQL**

Any help to make the connection work from the wrangler please?

Comment: I don't know Data Fusion, BUT I think you should just be able to specify the PostgreSQL connector, and then be sure that you have the Cloud SQL instance configured correctly to be reachable from Data Fusion. I'm not sure where the UI diverged from the docs... if you follow this guide: https://cloud.google.com/data-fusion/docs/how-to/reading-from-postgresql does that help?

Comment: @GabeWeiss Yes the earlier versions of the data fusion has the option to select the Cloud Sql For Postgres directly and option to use the Connection name. I have resolved the issue by selecting the database and adding the connection string like jdbc:postgresql://google/<DATABASE_NAME>?cloudSqlInstance=<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory. Thanks for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue by selecting the option `Database` and adding the connection like:

```
jdbc:postgresql://google/<DATABASE_NAME>?cloudSqlInstance=<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME>&socketFactory=com.google.cloud.sql.postgres.SocketFactory
```

Please note that the `INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME` should be in the format `<project>:<region>:<instance_name>`. Copy the exact connection name displayed on the GCP console's cloud SQL page.